# How could I have a custom, stored in database currency be a requirement to call a smart contract function for my NFT Game?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, nft, database

Im currently developing an NFT Game, where our idea is to have a custom currency that is stored in the database and serves to buy some items(stored in database aswell), and to breed the NFTs, how can I make it a comprobation that the caller of the function has that "currency disponible".

Im pretty new to this world, but in my understanding anyone can call that function from outside of the Game UI and bypass that requirement. I have read something about oracles but im not sure that its the correct way to do it.

Would it be better just to have a real token and do it with both smart contracts?

How could I make then exchanges from my "custom currency" to the token without incurring in the same problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "custom currency that is stored in the database". Please explain this statement. What is "database" for you ?

Comment: a normal centralized database, like a mysql database

Comment: What is the point of the blockchain if everything is in a centralized database ?

Comment: the only thing that is in the centralized database is some items to use on your nft, and some states the nft will have depending on a random value changing over time, the nft creation, the breeding and buying/selling will be on blockchain

Comment: the design is similar to PVU game